# sp_BlitzIndex performance concerns in production

Tags: sp-blitzindex

No real concern but I'm looking for some information of possible impact of running it on a busy server.  Should I Be concerned?

Would there be any loss of fidelity in the results by running it on a restored instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you run it on a restored instance, you won't get any data about which indexes are getting used, and which indexes SQL Server wishes it would have had.

So it's not really all that useful - however, it IS useful to understand how long sp_BlitzIndex will take to run. If you're worried about performance impacts, you can run it against a restored instance on similar hardware, and that'll tell you about the performance impact - but just don't take any actions based on the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running this on all my database server and have never seen any impact of this. It would return you tonnes of valuable information and if you tackle them one by one, most of your issues will disappear eventually.

Asking this for load on the server is like asking load on the car due to speedometer(Copied from Brent Ozar's one of video). There are different parameters you can run this procedure with, if you choose with bringthepain then its going to scan lot bunch of information to provide you detailed stuff. So, need to be a bit careful with that option and should run only in off hours or once in a while.